# webpack `publicPath`, `path` and webpack-dev-server `contentBase` relationship?

Tags: webpack

What's the relationship between them?

After reading `webpack` docs. I am still not very clear.

I know `output.path` clearly.

The docs say that `webpack-dev-server` will serve the `bundle` files in memory. So, what's the `contentBase` property meaning?

and what's the relationship with `publicPath`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems no relationship

"publicPath" is "URL path where the webpack files are served from", just like a url-prefix

"contentBase" is "the directory to serve files non-webpack files from", serve file not generate by webpack

More other info is here: [webpack-dev-server option](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/optionsSchema.json)